# 3 columns with third column having fluid width, fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet, html

I would like to do this simple layout:

1. 3 columns with left and right position:fixed because when scroll down, left and right supposed to stay still
2. We know left column `width = 200px`
3. We know middle column `width = 400px`
4. We DON'T know right column width and it should be **fluid** (i.e. fill in rest of the screen width OR zero)

This is the sample I have (but with **col3's width as 100px**). So the question is how to fix css of `col3` to make it fluid but still reserve `position:fixed`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Endt7/1/

My last alternative is to use jQuery. But I don't want to touch it unless really necessary for layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For absolute/fixed positioned elements, width is a function of left and right. So, set the `left: 600px; right: 0;` on the third column and browser will determine the width. That is it. Here is the revised CSS, with few changes for consistency:

```css
.col1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.col2 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
.col3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 600px;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Endt7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Can do it using `float:left` or absolute position for the left and middle columns and set `margin-left` equal to their combined widths.

```
.col1 {
    background: red;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;    
    height:100%
}

.col2 {
    background: green;    
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    height:100%

}

.col3 {
    background: blue;
    margin-left:600px;

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Endt7/3/

Comment: I look at your code and don't see blue anywhere? Did I miss something?

Comment: yes.. you did  same thing in display mode only. http://jsfiddle.net/Endt7/3/show/